# Как добавить ограничение размера при копирование файлов?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Для копирование файлов использую:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> nGetFiles(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
  Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
  return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption).Where(file => 
  reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file)));
}
public static void CopyDesktopFiles()
{
  string LookForExt = @"\.ico|\.txt|\.doc|\.jpg|\.html"; // форматы
  IEnumerable<string> files = nGetFiles(des, LookForExt);
  foreach (var f in files)
  {
      try
      {
        File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(str1, Path.GetFileName(f)),true);
      }
      catch(Exception) { }
  }
}
```

Ранее для проверки размера папки использовал данный способ:

```
public static void CopyDesktopFiles(string Mask, SearchOption Option = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
   const long LimitSizeFiles = 3 * 1024 * 1024;// не копировать файл больше 3МБ
   long HighLimit = 59000000;
   long LowLimit = 0;
   var ListFormat = new List<string>() { ".txt", ".doc", ".cs", ".Html", ".Dll", ".Xml", ".Php", ".json" };
   foreach (var Files in new DirectoryInfo(otkuda).EnumerateFiles(Mask, Option))
   {
      var ext = Path.GetExtension(Files.Name);
      int Check = ListFormat.IndexOf(ext);
      if (Check < LowLimit) continue;
      if ((HighLimit -= Files.Length) < LowLimit) break; // тут проверка
      try
      {
        if (ListFormat.Contains(ext) && Files.Length <= LimitSizeFiles)
            Files.CopyTo(Path.Combine(kudacopy, Files.Name));
      }
      catch { }
   }
}
```

Подскажите как в 1-ом методе добавить ограничение?

Пробовал сделать как и во 2-ом но не выходит, он просто копирует всё сразу.

Нужно добавить только ограничение размера папки при копирование файлов, и если размер превышает допустимый размер (`HighLimit = 59000000`) то завершить копирование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственное отличие новой версии от предыдущей в том, что в цикле работа ведется со строкой, вместо экземпляра [класса `FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Так как строка, в данном случае - это путь к файлу, можно изменить метод `nGetFiles` таким образом, чтобы он возвращал список [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) и можно будет использовать предыдущий код.

Например так:

```
private static IEnumerable<FileInfo> nGetFiles(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
  Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);
  return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption)
                  .Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file)))
                  .Select(file => new FileInfo(file));
}
```

---

Либо создавать экземпляр `FileInfo` непосредственно внутри `foreach` для проверки размера текущего файла.

Comment: @ArteS, в возвращаемом значении забыл поменять string на FileInfo

Comment: теперь он мне  в `CopyDesktopFiles()` выдаёт ошибки, так же исправил за место IEnumerable<string>, на `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` и в строке  `var ext = Path.GetExtension(Files);`  - (Files) ругается `не удается преобразовать из "System.IO.FileInfo" в "string".`

Comment: @ArteS, в каком из `CopyDesktopFiles`? Как я сказал в ответе, тебе достаточно вставить вызов nGetFiles в старую версию `CopyDesktopFiles` и все продолжит работать

Comment: прости, первый способ `public static void CopyDesktopFiles()`

Comment: @ArteS, а чем не устраивала предыдущая версия? по сути единственное что ты сделал - вынес `new DirectoryInfo(otkuda).EnumerateFiles(Mask, Option)` в отдельную функцию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59596/discussion-between-grundy-and-artes).